# how to make a video streaming URL only work inside the website?

Tags: javascript, http, video-streaming

so I tried to play a video streaming URL I took from a website inside VLC, but it plays me a short video saying that this video should and can only be played inside the original website

- How can they do that
- Is there any way to bypass that

The original website :
https://animeblkom.net/watch/boruto-naruto-next-generations/268

The URL I tried (the stream url):
https://cdn2.vid4up.xyz/video/16330290830432/download?token=63376d90a96df5.008509371167

Comment: It's just going to be a check on a cookie or referrer.

Comment: @Brad well how can I replicate that, assuming I have the cookie, how can I play that video outside the original website (using HLS.js or something like VLC for example)